# How to re-enable Tab auto-complete to fill in the API Name with underscores?

Tags: label, autocomplete

For as long as I can remember, and using my other friend's laptop when I type words like "Sample Report" as my Field label and press "Tab", the API Name should auto fill as "Sample_Report".

However my current laptop auto fills it as "SampleReport":

[image]

Is there a setting to re-enable the underscore fillings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it is due to **Browser** settings.

In Google Chrome for some reason, pressing 'Tab' makes it auto-complete to "SampleReport"

Whereas, in Firefox, pressing 'Tab' makes it auto-complete to "Sample_Report".